# How to append a dataframe to an existing empty dataframe with a loop?

Tags: python, csv

I want to fill an empty dataframe with data in csv files by using a loop.
The code works fine except that each time the dataframe records only the last csv file and not all the csv files that exist in the destination folder.

Did I do something wrong?

Here is a piece of my code :

```
csv_files = glob.glob(path +"/*.csv")

for csv_file in csv_files:

     columns_name = [A,B,C,D]
     newDF = pd.DataFrame( columns=columns_name)
     newDF = pd.concat([newDF,df])
     newDF.fillna('unknown', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `newDF` outside the loop:

```
csv_files = glob.glob(path +"/*.csv")

columns_name = [A,B,C,D]
newDF = pd.DataFrame( columns=columns_name)

for csv_file in csv_files:
     newDF = pd.concat([newDF,df])
     newDF.fillna('unknown', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Oh God , I did not even realize, thanks a lot zipa !